# How to add data label to histogram?

Tags: python-3.x

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/md7Pi.png)

Can someone show me how to add the number of freq on each histogram bin?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that I can extract the height of the bin then lable my bin using plt.text(). Thanks.